# What is the purpose of getTonightFromDatabase() in the Android Kotlin Room codelabs?

Tags: android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand codelab [6.2 Coroutines and Room](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-coroutines-and-room?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#6) in Android Kotlin Fundamentals. Class `SleepTrackerViewModel` includes (with comments added by me):

```kotlin
private var tonight = MutableLiveData<SleepNight?>()

private suspend fun getTonightFromDatabase(): SleepNight? {
    var night = database.getTonight()  // this gets the most recent night
    // Return null if this night has been completed (its end time has been set).
    if (night?.endTimeMilli != night?.startTimeMilli) {
        night = null
    }
    return night
}

fun onStartTracking() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val newNight = SleepNight()
        insert(newNight)
        tonight.value = getTonightFromDatabase()
    }
}

fun onStopTracking() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val oldNight = tonight.value ?: return@launch
        oldNight.endTimeMilli = System.currentTimeMillis()
        update(oldNight)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the method `getTonightFromDatabase()`, which is called only from `onStartTracking()`, is needed. It seems the last statement in `onStartTracking()` could be replaced by:

```
tonight.value = newNight
```

I also don't understand why the conditional in `getTonightFromDatabase()` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons is that the `nightId` in the `SleepNight` data class is auto generated by SQL.

If the code would do `tonight.value = newNight` then the `nightId` wouldn't be the same than the one in the database. That would cause the `update` call in `onStopTracking` to end (`update`) the wrong night.

Note too that the method `getTonightFromDatabase` is called from a [later version](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/5b4b66d29f34baf118f5d1bf036e4564ce2c94b9/TrackMySleepQualityCoroutines/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepTrackerViewModel.kt#L46) of `SleepNightViewModel`:

```kotlin
private var tonight = MutableLiveData<SleepNight?>()

init {
    initializeTonight()
}

private fun initializeTonight() {
   viewModelScope.launch {
       tonight.value = getTonightFromDatabase()
   }
}
```

When the application restarts, `getTonightFromDatabase` is called to set the instance variable `tonight` (which would more accurately be called `latestNight`). If the most recent night was complete, the completeness check would ensure that `null` is returned, prevent the entry from being modified.